# Refresh usercontrol on leave/lostfocus

Tags: vb.net

I have weird situation with usercontrol which contain only one textbox (for input numbers).
For example in "edit state" my text is unformatted and left aligned but after leaving control I would like a same text to be formatted and right aligned.
For that I use a code under textbox's "leave" event handler:

```
Private Sub numText_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles numText.Leave
    Debug.Print("numText_Leave")
    numText.TextAlign = def_Alignment ' right
    RefreshText()                     ' sub for formatting
End Sub
```

And what happens?
When program step into _Leave and set new alignment numText enters again and usercontrol don't want to exit. If I comment those code usercontrol exits normally but I can't get desired text showing (formatted).
Same happen's if I use numText_LostFocus instead of _Leave handler.

Any idea on what to do here?

EDIT:
After all, I found a solution.
Trick is in using textbox_Enter for entering and textbox_LostFocus for exiting.
Such pair of events don't raises textbox_Enter on setting textbox's alignment when exit.

Comment: Are you using the Control Box to exit the control? probably not what you are looking for, but could you put an 'OK' button on the form?

Comment: Hi Pat, I don't use control box and that way don't suit my needs. Same usercontrols I have in VB6 which behaves totally different.

Answer (score 0):

... I'm not sure I 100% understand your problem, but, from what I THINK I understand, I've had similar situations with controls recursively calling their events. I usually deal with it by creating an external boolean variable called, say, DoWork and do something as follows:

```
Dim DoWork as Boolean = True

Private Sub numText_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles numText.Leave
    If DoWork then
        DoWork = False
        Debug.Print("numText_Leave")
        NumText.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
        Refreshtext()
        DoWork = True
End Sub
```

... SOMETHING along those lines to stop it from keeping on going into the same function.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Hi John, I undestand your suggestion but problem is that I need code under _Leave to be executed when "_Leave" occurred. And that code enters textbox again and forbids usercontrol to exit.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? Maybe your `RefreshText()` so that I can truly see what your issue is because given what you posted, I cannot re-create the issue to solve it...